# Javascript: select others

Tags: javascript

I am working on an API where the plan is that the users fill in a short checklist with multiple options before a POST request is made. For each section the users gets multiple options / buttons, but only 1 of them can be selected.

The selected button will get the class `marked` (Which changes the background color to green) whilst the others remain white (unless one of them is clicked, in which case it turns green and the others become white)

I have tried two different Javascript functions, but so far none of them were able to get this behavior to work.

Attempt 1:

```
function Label(self, group) {
  //    mark button
  let btns = document.getElementsByClassName(group);

  for (el in btns) {
      btns[el].classList.remove('marked') 
  }
  self.classList.add('marked');
}
```

Attempt 2 (a more explicit check to see if `self` is involved)

```
function Label(self, group) {
      //    mark button
      let btns = document.getElementsByClassName(group);

      for (el in btns) {
          if (btns[el] !== self) {
              btns[el].classList.remove('marked')
          }

      }
      self.classList.add('marked');
    }
```

My reasoning was to first remove the `.marked` class from all elements, and then set it on the `this` element. As the function is called with the `onclick` command in the HTML it knows which of the elements it is.

```
<div class="group1">
    <button onclick="Label(this, pt_toggle)" class="pt_toggle">Incorrect</button>
    <button onclick="Label(this, pt_toggle)" class="pt_toggle">Partially correct</button>
    <button onclick="Label(this, pt_toggle)" class="pt_toggle">Correct</button>
</div>
```

However, the functions did not behave as I hoped. It throws an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined` error and the class is not set.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to pass 'this' or 'pt_toggle' in your Label function. You can get these infos from event.target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into a feature of the `for..in` loop syntax.  When you perform:

```
for (el in btns) {
    if (btns[el] !== self) {
        btns[el].classList.remove('marked');
    }
}
```

every property in the `btns` object will be iterated over, including the `length` property which you won't be able to remove a class name from `btns["length"]`.

If you switch to using a normal `for` loop using `btns.length` as the limit, you won't iterate over the non-button element properties in the object:

```
for (var el = 0; el < btns.length; el++) {
    if (btns[el] !== self) {
        btns[el].classList.remove('marked');
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jasper you can spread the collection aswell to perform a loop `for( el in [...btns] )`

Answer (score 1):

There is an element which performs this same kind of thing natively: [the radio button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio). This makes it easier to code a more concise solution (well, except the CSS to make it look like more a button, but that's optional):

```js
var buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".group1 .button"));
buttons.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    buttons.forEach((button) => button.classList.toggle("marked", button.querySelector("input").checked));
  });
});
```

```css
/* Hide the radio button */
.button input { display: none; }
/* make it green when selected */
.button.marked { 
  background: green
}
/* make the label look more like a button */
.button { 
  font: caption;
  font-size: smaller;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background: white;
}
.button:hover {
  border-color: ThreeDDarkShadow;
}
```

```html
<div class="group1">
    <label class="button"><input type="radio" name="pt_toggle">Incorrect</label>
    <label class="button"><input type="radio" name="pt_toggle">Partially correct</label>
    <label class="button"><input type="radio" name="pt_toggle">Correct</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding "marked" class on click to your button:

Your html:

```
<button onclick="Label(event)" class="pt_toggle">Incorrect</button>
```

Your js:

```
function Label(event) {
  event.target.classList.add("marked");
}
```